# UICollectionView Datasource Methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

UICollectionView has some built-in datasource methods, such as the "cellforItemAtIndexPath" method and the "numberofitemsinsection" method. If I understand correctly, these methods are called after viewDidLoad() completes. However, for my purposes, I want to be able to exactly control the point in time in which these methods are called. How can I do that?

The reason is that I am loading loading some images and I want to finish the task of loading before these methods are called.

Comment: if you want to trigger this method manually just reload the collection view  [self.collectionView reloadData];  or you need to do somthing in your app when hits these delegates then better you try a custom collectionview with a delgate which will do the needed

Comment: You can't.  You can trigger a specific series of calls, but you have no control after that point.  The closest you can come is to make sure the datasource property is not set until you want to trigger loading.

Comment: ok, the point is that I am downloading images and need them to finish downloading before these datasource methods are called. Since my image downloads are happening asynchronously, I currently lack the control to allow all my downloads to happen FIRST.

Comment: It's better to load the images asynchronously after the collectionview displays. Or if the images are absolutely crucial, you can show a spinner. 
After the images have been loaded, reload the collectionView and hide the spinner.
To answer your question: I don't think what you want is possible.

Comment: I have the spinner in viewDidLoad, but I get a compiler error from the datasource methods before the transition to the view even takes place. Since these datasource methods depend on the successful execution of the downloads, this is understandable. I could in theory use semaphores, but I don't really want to go down that path.

Comment: Okay so, what you can do, is make the images array or single variable optional, and in your datasource methods check if it's nil or not.
So in numberOfItemsInSection check if it's nil, if it is, return 0

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't want to show the collection until the images are downloaded, is that right? Does returning 0 for the number of items until the images finish downloading work? I don't have my Mac with me, or I'd test this before posting.

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: "You must have 50 reputation to comment"

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect the collectionView datasource and delegate connected to the controller from storyboard. Then set them in the code once you needed.

First connect the collectionView outlet to the interface section.

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
```

So once your images are loaded, call this method:-

```
self.collectionView.delegate= self;
self.collectionView.dataSource= self;
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```